# Best practice to style react components?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-tsx

I started working on an app made with tsx. This app has a general stylesheet for everything and some of the components have inline styling. Personally it feels disorganized.

I'm a biginner at css so I don't know what would be the best way to aproach this. I thought of two options: do all inline styling or make a stylesheet for each component. The first feels wrong ,in the second I'm gonna end up with 30 stylesheets and the overrides are going to mess up everithing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) library is universally popular and you'll find plenty of support from the large community that uses it. With this you can write your css inside your component files. I'd also recommend getting the VS-Code extension for it so that you get css intellisense.